# add field to all documents in mongodb collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i am working on node js project, i have a mongodb collection of orders in which i want to add a field to every document , the problem is that i want to pass a function as the value of this new field and the arguments of the function are two other fields of the document , this is an example that will make you understand .
my collection :

```
[
 {  
 _id:"eyxwapfhiezfe664ec",
 orderPrice : 20,
 createdAt :  2021-01-15T17:16:25.844Z
 endedAt : 2021-01-15T17:20:25.844Z
 
}
{
 _id:"eyxwlcfeojrfeoc",
  orderPrice : 50,
  createdAt :  2021-01-15T17:16:25.844Z
  endedAt : 2021-01-15T17:20:25.844Z
 
}
{
  _id:"eyxwapfhiseflflpsssc",
  orderPrice : 20, 
  createdAt :  2021-01-15T17:16:25.844Z
  endedAt : 2021-01-15T17:20:25.844Z
}
```

the field i want to add is completedTime which is the difference between createdAt and endedAt i have a function differenceBetweenDates which takes two dates as argument createdAt and ended at but i don't know how to pass this function to $set in update .
So to be more clear i want to add this field to every document :

```
CompletedTime: differenceBetweenDates(createdAt, endedAt)
```

thank you .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB 4.2, you can pass aggregation expressions as part of the [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/#update-one-update).

```
db.collection.updateMany({},[{ $set:{ CompletedTime: {$subtract:["$endedAt", "$createdAt" ]}}}])
```

In MongoDB 4.4 you might also use an aggregation pipeline with a [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#merge-aggregation) stage to merge the result set back into the original collection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { CompletedTime: {$subtract:["$endedAt", "$createdAt" ]}}},
  { $merge: "collection" }
])
```

Comment: i don't think that $substract will give me the right result because my function differenceBetweenTwoDates give me the difference in hours i don't know if this is possible with $substract

Comment: Subtract will give you the difference in milliseconds, divide by 3600000 if you need that in hours.